# Error loading PHP modules

Tags: php, windows, apache

I'm running PHP 5.2.8 on Apache 2.2.11 on Windows XP SP 3. In php.ini,

```
extension_dir = "C:\Program Files\PHP\ext"
extension=php_mysql.dll
```

In error.log:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\\Program Files\\PHP\\ext\\php_mysql.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
```

php_mysql.dll is definately located in the extension_dir, and is the version that PHP 5.2.8 is bundled with. What's up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a **trailing slash** to your `extension_dir` path.

This is what I am using in my WAMP setup:

```
extension_dir = "D:\php\ext\"
; ...snip...
extension=php_gd2.dll
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try

extension_dir = "C:/Program Files/PHP/ext"

Edit: No, not that. Seems you need to add it to the PATH variable in Windows: https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.windows.iis.php

Comment: The OP is using Apache, not IIS.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the MySQL client library available to PHP. This is done by copying the libmysql.dll file from the PHP package root directory into a directory on your system within the Windows PATH.

The quickest way to do this is to copy libmysql.dll into your C:\Windows\System directory but as noted in the manual, this is not recommended and is just a quick fix to see if it is actually the problem here.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysql.installation.php says:

> MySQL is no longer enabled by default,
> so the php_mysql.dll DLL must be
> enabled inside of php.ini. Also, PHP
> needs access to the MySQL client
> library. A file named libmysql.dll is
> included in the Windows PHP
> distribution and in order for PHP to
> talk to MySQL this file needs to be
> available to the Windows systems PATH.
> See the FAQ titled "How do I add my
> PHP directory to the PATH on Windows"
> for information on how to do this.
> Although copying libmysql.dll to the
> Windows system directory also works
> (because the system directory is by
> default in the system's PATH), it's
> not recommended.

The best option is to [add the PHP directory into your Windows PATH, which is explained in this FAQ](https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.installation.php#faq.installation.addtopath).